# 5 fold Cross-validation

Tags: r, cross-validation, r-caret

I have used this code to perform a 5 fold cross-validation on the Davis dataset found in the carData library.

```
install.packages("caret")
library(caret)
trainControl<-trainControl(method="cv",number=5)
lm<-train(weight~height+repht+repwt,Davis,method="lm",trControl=trainControl)
lm
```

Running this I obtain the error saying that there are missing values for weight.
This is the error message:

> Error in na.fail.default(list(weight = c(77L, 58L, 53L, 68L, 59L, 76L, : missing values in object

I would be very grateful for any suggestions on how to solve this problem. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please do not set an object equal to `lm`. `lm` is a reserved name for fitting a linear model. instead use `LM` or `fit_lm` or something of that nature. Same thing for `trainControl`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have missing errors in your predictor, so for example:

```
library(caret)
data = mtcars
data$mpg[c(3,6,9)]<-NA
trainControl<-trainControl(method="cv",number=5)
fit<-train(mpg~cyl+hp,data,method="lm",trControl=trainControl)

Error in na.fail.default(list(mpg = c(21, 21, NA, 21.4, 18.7, NA, 14.3,  : 
  missing values in object
```

Use complete.cases to get data that contains complete observations

```
complete.obs = complete.cases(data[,c("mpg","cyl","hp")])
data = data[complete.obs,]
fit<-train(mpg~cyl+hp,data,method="lm",trControl=trainControl)
```

In your case, it should be:

```
complete.obs = Davis[,c("weight","height","repht","repwt")]
```